# Eliminating specific items from a list in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to figure out how to loop through a list I have and eliminate certain items in that list based on whether they include a specific word in it.

Here's my code so far:

```
for container in containers:
    days = container.findAll('p',{'class':'period-name'})
    #Assigns all of the classes of the day names to days
    for day_descriptor in days:
        day = day_descriptor.text
        #loops through days classes and stores those each of those in a day
    forecasts = container.findAll('p',{'class':'short-desc'})
    for forecast_descriptor in forecasts:
        forecast = forecast_descriptor.text
        #loops through forecasts classes and stores those each of those in a forecast
    print(day)
```

The list day shows as:

```
day = ['Tonight', 'Friday', 'FridayNight', 'Saturday', 'SaturdayNight', 'Sunday', 'SundayNight', 'Monday', 'MondayNight']
```

However, I don't want any of these items that include the word 'Night' (excluding if the word is 'Tonight') to be contained within this list. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the data as is, so that when Night is compounded with the day of the week and the N is capitalized, then I can treat that separately from Tonight by filtering out the entries that contain Night.

For example, here's a list comprehension solution:

```
>>> days = ['Tonight', 'Friday', 'FridayNight', 'Saturday', 'SaturdayNight', 'Sunday', 'SundayNight', 'Monday', 'MondayNight']
>>> new_days = [day for day in days if 'Night' not in day]
```

But if you'd prefer to break it out you can simply do:

```
corrected_days = []
for day in days:
    if 'Night' not in day:
        corrected_days.append(day)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if night is present in your text.

For example: **Assuming day_descriptor.text is text not list**

```
if  'night' not in day_descriptor.text:
     day.append( day_descriptor.text)
```

or from the day you can select only the necessary things.

```
[d for d in day if not 'Night' in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `endswith` over `in`:

```
day = [name for name in day 
       if not name.endswith('Night')]
```

If it must be case insensitive:

```
day = [name for name in day 
       if not name.lower().endswith('night') or name.lower() == 'tonight']
```